# spring boot scheduling enable/disable tasks in method level

Tags: java, spring-boot, scheduled-tasks

I am following this guide to start scheduling tasks in spring boot
https://spring.io/guides/gs/scheduling-tasks/.

I want to add more methods for different tasks in the same class, wondering if it is possible to enable/disable the tasks on the method level via the properties and `@ConditionalOnProperty`, seems `@ConditionalOnProperty` works on the class level only, not the method level(as per the code example below, which doesn't work). Any alternative approaches? Or have to create another class including task two in order to disable/enable them separately?

```
@Component    
public class SchedulingTasks {

    private static final Logger log =    LoggerFactory.getLogger(SchedulingTasks.class);

    @Scheduled(fixedRate = 50000)
    public void jobOne() {
        log.info("job one started at {}", LocalDateTime.now());
    }

    @Scheduled(fixedRate = 50000)
    @ConditionalOnProperty(name="job.two", havingValue="true")  
    public void jobTwo() {
        log.info("just two started at {}", LocalDateTime.now());
    }
}
```

Comment: I would just go with creating separate classes.

Comment: Do you have `job.two=true` in your `app.properties` file?

Comment: yes, i have job.two=false in application.properties file, however both methods logs the information. with the same property setting, if move @ConditionalOnProperty annotation on the class level, both methods wouldn't log the information.

Comment: you can only use ```@ConditionalOnProperty``` as a method-level annotation when it returns a ```@Bean```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can apply [`@ConditionalOnProperty`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/api/org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/condition/ConditionalOnProperty.html) to methods as well as types, but it appears that this only applies to methods that register Beans (see [`@Conditional`](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/4.0.0.RELEASE/javadoc-api/org/springframework/context/annotation/Conditional.html) documentation).

You should create separate Beans where you can control registration with @ConditionalOnProperty and then apply the [`@Scheduled`](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/scheduling/annotation/Scheduled.html) annotation to a method within the Bean.

Example:

```java
@Slf4j
@Service
@ConditionalOnProperty(prefix = "schedule", name = {"job.one"}, havingValue = "true")
public class JobOneScheduler {

    @Scheduled(cron = "*/2 * * * * *")
    public void runJob() {
        log.debug( "Running job one... {}", LocalDateTime.now() );
    }
}


@Slf4j
@Service
@ConditionalOnProperty(prefix = "schedule", name = {"job.two"}, havingValue = "true")
public class JobTwoScheduler {
    @Scheduled(cron = "*/5 * * * * *")
    public void runJob() {
        log.debug( "Running job two... {}", LocalDateTime.now() );
    }
}
```

application.properties:

```
schedule.job.one=true
schedule.job.two=false
```